# Using WM_SETTEXT to set Notepad text is not affecting Text_Changed event in the Notepad instance

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, winapi, pinvoke

I've almost completed a project that will basically, take the contents of a .txt file, open a new notepad instance using 'Process.Start("notepad")' and then set the text using the "WM_SETTEXT" constant. I have this working beautifully so I don't need any assistance with setting the text. However, I have one small issue I noticed during testing. After the text is set in the notepad instance, if you close the notepad window, it does NOT ask if you wish to save the changes. This led me to believe that "WM_SETTEXT" does NOT fire the "Text_Changed" event in the notepad instance.

After some thinking, I realized that it could also mean that notepad only asks to save changes if a user types something manually. So perhaps rather than checking for "Text_Changed" it may be checking for a "Mouse_Down" event?? Whichever one it may be, I would like some input from someone with a little more knowledge as to the 'internal' workings of notepad and how it checks if there were 'changes' to the text that need to be saved.

Here is part of my SetText function:

```
        if (FileIO.Index != null && FileIO.Index.Count > 0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Recovering " + FileIO.Index.Count + " files...");
            foreach (string guid in FileIO.Index)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(guid))
                {
                    string contents = "";
                    if (!FileIO.Recover(guid, out contents))
                        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't recover '" + guid + "'");
                    else
                    {
                        Process p = Process.Start("notepad");
                        Thread.Sleep(200);
                        SetText(GetNotepadEditBox(p.MainWindowHandle), contents);
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Recovered all files successfully!", "Done recovering files!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
```

Methods:

```
private static IntPtr GetNotepadEditBox(IntPtr hParentWindow)
{
    return Win32.FindWindowEx(hParentWindow, IntPtr.Zero, "Edit", null);
}

private void SetText(IntPtr hEditBox, string text)
{
    IntPtr len = new IntPtr(text.Length);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(text);

    Win32.SendMessage(hEditBox, Win32.WM_SETTEXT, len, sb);

    sb = null;
    len = IntPtr.Zero;
}
```

Comment: You could try copying your text to the clipboard and then send a WM_PASTE command instead of WM_SETTEXT.

Comment: That's actually not a half-bad idea, however, it's not feasible as this software will be recovering anywhere from 10-50 notepad files at one time. Nor do I want to replace a user's clipboard text while running recovery software;) But having said that, I've never used WM_PASTE before, so out of curiousity, what would be the benefit of using that versus let's say, copying the text to the clipboard, retrieving it using Clipboard.GetText(), then using WM_SETTEXT instead of WM_PASTE?

Comment: Why on Earth are you messing with Notepad?  It is just a TextBox.  Simply create your own.

Comment: That's completely irrelevant, and I'm glad we're on the same page about it being simple to "create my own," thanks for the insight;) But I have a client who uses notepad religiously to take quick notes, but tends to forget to save them and then has a power outage, turns his computer off, etc and loses all his notes. I mentioned the idea of creating another notepad with an 'autosave' feature but he doesn't want that b/c he "likes the feel" of notepad. Regardless, the issue still remains, and if you have any ideas for me I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The edit control keeps the properties *text* and *modified* as distinct entities, allowing applications to build their own modification management around them. Sending a [`WM_SETTEXT` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632644.aspx) does not automatically set the *modified* flag. To set this flag you have to explicitly send an [`EM_SETMODIFY` message](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761651.aspx) to the edit control.

Comment: Thank you for that. I researched it further and discovered the EM_SETMODIFY constant myself and tried to answer my own question about 10 mins ago, however I don't have enough reputation to do so! lol